# Corrupted database. How to restore it from an old backup and add newer changes after?

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore, ssms, corruption

I have a corrupted database with the following error

```
Msg 8952, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: table 'sys.syscolpars' (ID 41). Index row of index 'nc' (ID 2) does not match any row of data. Additional or invalid keys for:
Msg 8956, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Index row (1:96551:30) with values (id = 1059235274 and name = 'binary_message_body' and number = 0 and colid = 15) pointing to the row of data identified by (id = 1059235274 and number = 0 and colon = 15).
Msg 8952, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: table 'sys.syscolpars' (ID 41). Index row of index 'nc' (ID 2) does not match any row of data. Additional or invalid keys for:
Msg 8956, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Index row (1:96551:32) with values (id=1059235274 and name='conversation_handle' and number=0 and colid=5) pointing to data row identified by (id=1059235274 and number=0 and package = 5).
```

I've been advised to restore from a non-corrupted backup. The problem is that the most recent one dates several weeks back. There are some later full backups, but they already have that consistency error. Could I somehow get the differential backup between the stable backup and my latest version? I have tried to do it using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio on a Windows Server 2019, but I think it contains the difference with to the last created backup (which already contains corrupted data) and I don't know how to find the difference between the stable backup and the data that I currently have.

Is there a way to delete specific backups so it considers the stable backup as the latest one?

I'm using this version:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU15) (KB5008996) - 15.0.4198.2 (X64)   Jan 12 2022 22:30:08   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)
```

Comment: Maybe try a full rebuild of your database by copying all tables over into a new one? Or restore the backup and try to reconcile the changes?

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface, but I'm not sure how to do that. How do I reconcile the changes?

Comment: You would have to write `MERGE` statements for every table which compare by primary key and add, delete or update any rows needed. Probably better to start with straight copies of whatever you have. SSMS Import/Export Wizard might be a good place to start, there are others also. If any table fails then do a `MERGE` over a backup. Don't forget to copy all view, function, procedure and type definitions, as well as indexes, and any management data like certificates and users

Answer (score 2):

> Table error: table 'sys.syscolpars' (ID 41). Index row of index 'nc' (ID 2)

Is this the complete error message ?. The `index ID is 2` is non-clustered index as per the error message you have posted. Try rebuilding the index it "may" fix the corruption, but since system tables are involved its most unlikely.

> Is there a way to delete specific backups so it considers the stable backup as the latest one?

No that would not be possible. The restore always follow below sequence
Full backup--Diff backup--Log backup.
or
Full backup--All log backups in sequence. If you have Last full backup which is not corrupted and then "ALL" log backups post that you would be able to get the database restored as near as possible to the corrupt one.

Other Options:

Could you try taking backup of current DB with `continue_after_error`
`backup database db_name to disk='Drive\folder\db.bak' with continue_after_error`.
Now try restoring it with `continue_after_error` and then run checkdb with `repair_allow_data_loss` to see how much data you loose.

Meanwhile also try to see how much data you loose with current stable backup, by restoring it. The amount of work needed is tedious but that is the way out here as I see.

> Could I somehow get the differential backup between the stable backup and my latest version?

The diff backup will be linked to full backup after which it was taken so unless you restore that full backup, assuming it is stable and consistent, it would be of no use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have some doubts:

- How can I rebuild the index? I haven't found any documentation about these tables and I don't understand what they do. They are 16 consistency errors in total, so it might be feasible to do.

- How do I restore "All log backups"? Do they refer to the transactions being done in the database? 

- I've tried already checkdb with repair_allow_data_loss and repair_rebuild. It detects the 16 consistency errors, but then there is a crash of MSSQL CHECKDB with EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION and process is terminated

Comment: @charade `sys.syscolpars` is a [system table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/system-base-tables?view=sql-server-ver15), which you can only access via a DAC connection. It's unlikely that it will allow an index rebuild (these tables are normally read-only) but you could try. `DBCC` should not crash the server whatever the issue is, if it is doing so then report a bug.